# Is it possible to store session in two different stores using Spring Session and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I am using redis for storing session in my Spring Boot app. I am also using Spring Session library to achieve this. I have two different redis instances namely `US redis` and `EU redis`. Once someone enters my app(after logging in of course), I want to store their sessions in both `US redis` and `EU redis` servers. Mind you that these both redis instances are masters and are not in any master-slave setup. This is what I have so far in my spring setup.

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig{

}
```

Note: removed other security code for brevity.

According to [@EnableRedisHttpSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.html) docs, we need to add one `RedisConnectionFactory` instance, however Spring Boot by default does this.

So right now, once the user logs in, their session is stored in `US redis`(I added US redis related information in `application.yml`).

However whenever a session is stored in `US redis`, I want to replicate the same in `EU redis` server. How can I achieve this? Do I need to create another `RedisConnectionFactory` bean and manually save it? If manually save it, how to do so?

**Note**: This use case might not be following the best design practices(that is we are storing user session in multiple places). However I do understand this, but I do have a use case for this.

Answer (score 1):

Replication is done by the underlying connection. For example, if you are using Lettuce with Spring Session Redis, then you would set it up with a [Master Slave setup](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Master-Slave). In Spring you can refer to [Connecting to Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors) section of the documentation.

Spring Boot provides simple mechanism for setting up master/slave via properties. This [article](https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-boot-sample-application-with-redis-master-slave-cluster/) has a nice summary. In short, add the properties to application.yml

```
redis:
  master:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  slaves:
    - host: localhost
      port: 16379
    - host: localhost
      port: 26379
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a built in solution for that, but you can always tweak the spring code or as you wrote sent an explicit `set` to the remote Redis.

You might want to consider using some [Active-Active](https://redislabs.com/landing/active-active/) replication mechanism like [CRDT](https://redislabs.com/docs/under-the-hood/)